# When and why does trac itself change trac.ini?

Tags: trac

Are there occasions where trac rewrites / resets `trac.ini` on its own?

During normal operation, I sometimes get the error "The environment needs to be upgraded."

However I found that this, apparently, is due to trac resetting `trac.ini`, with e.g. the `[ticket-workflow]` section gone missing, as a diff shows.

Restoring `trac.ini` to a recent backup makes the "upgrade" notice disappear, and operations resume as before. But I'd rather prefer trac not messing with `trac.ini` unless instructed to do so.

Any hints how to fix this will be appreciated.

- trac 1.0.9
- TracAccountManager 0.4.2
- TracSubTicketsPlugin 0.2.0.dev20160107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply by RjOllos on the trac-users mailing list:

> The loss of [ticket-workflow] is not expected behavior. What is expected behavior: when ticket-workflow is missing, Trac will prompt you to upgrade 
>   the environment, which then restores the default ticket-workflow section.
>
> Trac normally changes trac.ini when an update is applied from the Admin 
>   pages, and that update needs to be stored in trac.ini rather than the 
>   database. Otherwise, Trac won't modify trac.ini. [...] plugins 
>   have access to trac.ini, so a plugin could inadvertently do something bad.
>
> [...] you should probably upgrade to AccountManagerPlugin 
>   0.4.4. See changelog and #10871 for more info.
>
> https://trac-hacks.org/browser/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4/changelog
>
> https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/10871